# select return zero but there are more data and recv works too

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, winsock, vnc

I am using LibVNC and by turning on the logs(which show bytes sent and recieved) I can see that server is sending data. But my client stops recieving data at some point.
I debugged it and came into that: in my client select function returns value of zero.
Although if I change the return value via debugger, recv continues to work and recieves data in order posted from server. so it seems everything is working fine.

I am running both client and server in the same machine, so using localhost.

I dont know if it helps but this is piece of code that returns zero.

any suggestions where should I dig to find problem?

```
int WaitForMessage(rfbClient* client,unsigned int usecs)
{
  fd_set fds;
  struct timeval timeout;
  int num;

  timeout.tv_sec=(usecs/1000000);
  timeout.tv_usec=(usecs%1000000);

  FD_ZERO(&fds);
  FD_SET(client->sock,&fds);

  num=select(client->sock+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
  if(num<0) {
    errno=WSAGetLastError();
    rfbClientLog("Waiting for message failed: %d (%s)\n",errno,strerror(errno));
  }

      return num;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`select()` returns 0 when its `timeout` period elapses, so double check your `timeout` is accurate.  Remember that `tv_sec` is expressed in **seconds** and `tv_usec` is expressed in **microseconds** (1/1000000 of a second). What is your `usecs` parameter expressed in?  Microseconds are very unusual to work with in Windows programming, **milliseconds** (1/1000 of a second) are more common.  What value are you specifying in your `usecs` parameter when `select()` is returning 0? Chances are you are not handling the `usecs` properly and the resulting `timeout` is much smaller than you are expecting.